# How do I convert an XML file into a dataframe/tibble in R?

Tags: r, xml, dplyr, xml2

How do I convert an XML file that looks like this:

```
<bible>
  <b n="Psalm">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="2"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="3"> text text text text </v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="2"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="3"> text text text text </v>
  </c>
  </b>
  <b n="Revelation">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="2"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="3"> text text text text </v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="2"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="3"> text text text text </v>
    </c>
    <c n="3">
      <v n="1"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="2"> text text text text </v>
      <v n="3"> text text text text </v>
    </c>
  </b>
</bible>
```

Into a dataframe/tibble format that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
 book       chapter verse text               
 <chr>        <dbl> <int> <chr>              
1 Psalm            1     1 text text text text
2 Psalm            1     2 text text text text
3 Psalm            1     3 text text text text
4 Psalm            2     1 text text text text
5 Psalm            2     2 text text text text
6 Psalm            2     3 text text text text
7 Revelation       1     1 text text text text
8 Revelation       1     2 text text text text
9 Revelation       1     3 text text text text
10 Revelation       2     1 text text text text
11 Revelation       2     2 text text text text
12 Revelation       2     3 text text text text
13 Revelation       3     1 text text text text
14 Revelation       3     2 text text text text
15 Revelation       3     3 text text text text
```

I've tried using `xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "/bible"))` from the XML package but I just get one observation with multiple columns. When I tried changing node levels for the getNodeSet function I get a `duplicate subscripts for columns` error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files and sibling to XPath. Specifically, you need to flatten all data down into a single level such as *verse* where you migrate ancestor nodes or attributes to sibling nodes, of course repeating values for data frame setup.

Once transformed you can then use the convenience method `XML::xmlToDataFrame` suitable for flatter XML. R can run XSLT 1.0 with the `xslt` package (extension to `xml2`)

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/bible">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::v"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v">
        <data>
            <book><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::b/@n"/></book>
            <chapter><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::c/@n"/></chapter>
            <verse><xsl:value-of select="@n"/></verse>
            <text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></text>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**R** *(no loops or mapping needed)*

```
library(XML)
library(xslt)

doc <- read_xml("Import.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("Script.xsl", package = "xslt")

new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

new_doc <- XML::xmlParse(new_xml)    
bible_df <- XML::xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(new_doc, "//data"))
```